# Refactoring for image versions and rails transforming locals for partials into symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Using the carrierwave gem to generate various versions of images, these can be invoked to generate the required image by referring to its [version name](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions)

```
style='background: url(<%= pict.image_url(:small).to_s %>);'
```

Integrating these to a framework, such as foundation, that handles the viewports

```
<div class='show-for-small-only'>
  <%= render partial: 'items', locals: { size: 'small'} %>
</div>
<div class='show-for-medium-only'>
  <%= render partial: 'items', locals: { size: 'medium'} %>
</div>
```

How can one invoke the local as a symbol, as the following generates a syntaxic error

```
style='background: url(<%= pict.image_url(:#{size}).to_s %>);'
```

Comment: You don't have to convert to a symbol, passing a string will do the job. In case you really do have to convert to a symbol, you can do `size.to_sym`

Answer (score 0):

the proper call has two sets of renderings and thus the inner one requires double quotes for interpretation:

```
style='background: url(<%= pict.image_url("#{size.to_sym}").to_s %>);'
```